# How to change all PK seed values in hybris?

Tags: groovy, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to change all generated keys in hybris system. I'm using oracle database with hybris 6.3+

Comment: Why would you want to change the PK's? As the keys are already generated, this means you need to change the PK of the object, and of all tables where this object is used

Comment: There was a situation where we have migrated to new DB and hybris was throwing duplicate and unique constrain issues while saving a model. So we used this script to change all PK values.

Comment: Did you also migrate the table "NumberSeries"? That one should contain all numberseries that are in use. As long as you don't reset that series, no collisions should occur. What your script does is just a random skip in your number series. A lot will depend on how much data is already in your database.

Comment: Yes, We migrated the numberseries table too. But while creating new model there was dups so we randomized the values and already existing data's pk will be same it will be take effect on creating the new model.

Answer (score 0):

I used below groovy to solve generate new pk current value

```
import de.hybris.platform.core.Registry;
import de.hybris.platform.core.PK.PKCounterGenerator;
import de.hybris.platform.persistence.numberseries.SerialNumberGenerator;
import de.hybris.platform.jalo.numberseries.NumberSeriesManager;

numberseriesmanager = spring.getBean("default.core.numberSeriesManager");

Collection<String> keys = numberseriesmanager.getAllNumberSeriesKeys();
for(String ke : keys){
    if(ke.contains('pk_')) {
        String[] keyWrd = ke.split("_");
        int keyint = Integer.parseInt(keyWrd[1]);
        int current = new de.hybris.platform.core.DefaultPKCounterGenerator().fetchNextCounter(keyint);
        SerialNumberGenerator generator = Registry.getCurrentTenant().getSerialNumberGenerator();
        generator.removeSeries("pk_" + ke);
        generator.createSeries("pk_" + ke, 1, current * 3)
    }
}
```